# Seated Shoulder Press vs Single Dumbbell Front Raises

Tags: shoulders, dumbbells

Yesterday, I was doing **Seated Shoulder Press** ([ExRx](https://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/DBShoulderPress.html)), with good posture, but then the gym trainer came and stopped me and told me to do **Single Dumbbell Front Raises** ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFNaDzE7VVc)) instead. And he also told me that Front Raise is easier than Shoulder Press and targets the same muscles.

So, is the later one better than the former, or was it because he thought my form wasn't right? I tried searching online, but couldn't find much about it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't ask those questions to your trainer?

Comment: I don't like him. And I did, he said it's easier and why do the hard thing if you can do the easy thing.